# Changing the writing language

Tags: languages, babel, greek

I write in greek (having before load all the necessary packages and own commands - babel etc). In order to change the language and write a word in english I type `\gre` and the letters appear with english characters (that is correct!). The problem is that whenever I want to come back and write greek again I use the command `\eng` and typeset the desired word ...but the first letter of it is in english!
My own commands are:

```
\newcommand{\eng}[1]{\latintext#1\greektext} % Change language
\newcommand{\gre}[1]{\greektext\latintext#1} % Change language
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`) or hit Ctrl+K.

Comment: Which of the [options described here](http://www.eelvex.net/latex/greek-in-latex/) are you using? Your commands look as if they’re intended to be used like this: `ελληνικά \eng{English} ελληνικά` (single English word amidst Greek text) or `English \gre{ελληνικά} English` (vice versa). In this case the definition of the latter is wrong and should read `\newcommand{\gre}[1]{\greektext#1\latintext}`.

Comment: The predefined commands `\greektext` and `\latintext` work as switches like font size commands (e.g. `\large`), but due to `[1]` in `\newcommand` your commands expect a single parameter which is used where `#1` appears. When used without curly braces, i.e. `\eng English` instead of `\eng{English}`, they will consume the first non-whitespace character (here: ’E‘).

Answer (score 8):

Your definitions are wrong. Besides, having `\latintext` doesn't guarantee correct hyphenation of English words. Here's a better way (the Greek sentence has been obtained from Google translation, I don't know if it's good Greek).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

\begin{document}

Αυτό το κείμενο είναι στα Ελληνικά \foreignlanguage{english}{not English}

\begin{otherlanguage*}{english}
This is a longer text in English, so
we use an environment for it.
\end{otherlanguage*}

Αυτό το κείμενο είναι στα Ελληνικά

\end{document}
```

Of course you might prefer defining a personal command, such as

```
\newcommand{\eng}[1]{\foreignlanguage{english}{#1}}
```

so you can simply type `\eng{English word}` in your document instead of the complicated `\foreignlanguage{english}{English word}`.

[image]